# jquery attr on firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, attr

I'm doing full screen background change system with jQuery.
When enter to site makes full screen size default background, and when click button must change background. Everything works fine on opera! But FireFox nothink happend. I think problem is with attr function, please help found problem.

All this you can see in http://www.hiphopdance.lt

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//default actions
var now_img="images/bg.jpg";
resize(1600,900,"#bgimg",now_img);
$(window).bind("resize", function() { resize(1600,900,"#bgimg"); });
//default actions end

//clicks
$('li#red').click(function(){
$("img#bgimg").attr({src:'http://www.hiphopdance.lt/images/redbg.jpg'});
resize(1024,683,"#bgimg");
$(window).bind("resize", function() { resize(1024,683,"#bgimg"); });
});
//end clicks

//resize function start
function resize(img_width,img_height,img_id)
{
  var ratio = img_height / img_width;    
  // Get browser window size
  var browserwidth = $(window).width();
  var browserheight = $(window).height();
  // Scale the image
  if ((browserheight/browserwidth) > ratio){
      $(img_id).height(browserheight);
    $(img_id).width(browserheight / ratio);
  } else {
    $(img_id).width(browserwidth);
    $(img_id).height(browserwidth * ratio);
  }
  // Center the image
  $(img_id).css('left', (browserwidth - $(img_id).width())/2);
  $(img_id).css('top', (browserheight - $(img_id).height())/2);
}; 
//resize function end        

});
```

---

thanks for answer, i has tried change from

```
$("img#bgimg").attr({src:'http://www.hiphopdance.lt/images/redbg.jpg'});
```

to

```
$("img#bgimg").attr("src","http://www.hiphopdance.lt/images/redbg.jpg");
```

still works on opera but not on firefox / IE

Comment: Btw you can use $(function () { }); rather than $(document).ready(function(){ });

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img#bgimg").attr("src","http://www.hiphopdance.lt/images/redbg.jpg");
```

key, value

You can also use Firebug for firefox, it has a javascript console which will return any JS errors.

Comment: @Tomas, lets see your html then.

Comment: <body>
<img id="bgimg" src="images/bg.jpg" /> 
<div id="realBody">MY SITE</div>
</body>

also you can visit htt://www.hiphopdance.lt and see ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!  Problem was in css file, becouse backround have z-index:-1, and all site z-index:5. I chnaget from 5 to 0. and